# Looking for a name of a cartoon/animated movie from 90's

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

In this cartoon a bunch of friends transform with powerful suits/weapons along with their cars/bikes to fight the bad guy.

He has a giant head (not MODOK) like computerized and a robotic mask. He was broad shouldered and always wore a black cape/overall. There was this girl by his side at all time.

And the protagonist had a flaming sword for a weapon.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Hello Mahesh, welcome to [fantasy.se] and thank you for your question. _Where_ was this cartoon broadcast? That would be very helpful information. You can [edit] your question to add this information, or any additional details you might remember. You can also read [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/19561) to asking story ID requests. Lastly, may I invite you to take the [tour]?

Comment: Flaming sword makes me think of Thundarr the Barbarian, but that doesn't match the other parts.

Comment: If you leave out the cars, and allow for a large helmet instead of a mask, *Galtar and the Golden Lance* pretty much hits all of the points.

Answer (score 3):

Transforming suits and vehicles makes me think of M.A.S.K., a cartoon and toyline where both the heroes and the villains got their powers from, you guessed it, masks. Both heroes and villains had transforming vehicles.

[image: MASK Splash image]

Miles Mayhem, the main villain, does wear a large mask (as does everyone else), but no cape. Instead, he kept his military suit (he's the one in the blue just to the right of center in the above image). Also, I don't think flaming swords came up. Still, it's the best match I've found so far.

**Opening**

Comment: Lack of flaming sword and no constant girl companion are the problems with this answer. Although it is certainly the first thing I thought of after reading the Question.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible you're trying to find the 1987 series [Visionaries](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092476/), it reached Europe in 1989.

### Opening

[image: When a cape ins't a cape]

As you can see from the opening sequence, we've got the fancy vehicles and the masks again. Visionaries comes a bit closer on the flaming sword, given the weird energy/green smokiness that infuses quite a few of medieval weapons that the characters wave around.

Capes don't seem to be a common feature, but I did find a few in deviant art images which I can't really count as canon, but the image above shows how there are plenty of opportunities for things that aren't capes to look like them.

Still missing a constant girl companion.

Answer (score 1):

Another partially matching answer (included, as much as anything, for the sake of other people searching for similar works), is *Galtar and the Golden Lance*. Its sole non-matching point is a lack of vehicles.

> The series is about the mythical sword-and-sorcery adventures of three companions: Galtar, Princess Goleeta, and her younger mind controlling brother Zorn. Galtar, with the help of his Golden Lance, is fighting with Tormack, the tyrannical usurper of the kingdom of Bandisar, who is conquering their entire world. Tormack is responsible for the death of both Galtar's parents and assassinating the rest of Goleeta and Zorn's family.
>
> Tormack, among others like him, covets the power of Galtar's supernatural weapon, the Golden Lance, to combine it with the stolen ancient and indestructible Sacred Shield, which rightfully belongs to Goleeta and Zorn. For whoever holds both becomes invincible—such a wielder cannot be brought down in any form of combat. The Golden Lance itself normally exists as a rather ordinary-looking short staff. However, whenever Galtar holds it above his head with both hands, it extends two mystical blades from itself, one on each side, and can then be divided into two swords for dueling. The enchantment that gives the Golden Lance its power also causes any unworthy wielder to bring about an uncontrolled discharge of magical energy from its "hilt," which is called "The Fury Of The Golden Lance." (This is actually shown in at least one of the episodes.)

Galtar's "lance" looks like a flaming sword. Tormack wears a dark cloak and is often accompanied by Rava, his niece (before she joins the good guys), and is very broad-shouldered.

**Intro**